# How to get MPLAB X v6.00 to instantiate an 'S' type file

Tags: mplabx

Since I have written dozens of PIC assembly language programs, I'm trying to write another one for the new pic-as assembler.  When I indicate that I'm developing a new assembly program, using the pic-as (v2.35) for a PIC 18F26K42 processor, and start to write my code in 'main', the IDE automatically assigns it an 's' type of file.  However, I've seen comments that this must be an 'S' type of file.  How do I do this?  I've gone to rename the main.s file in my MPLAB projects folder to main.S, but then the IDE keeps looking for the 's' type file.
I do know that the include file for xc.inc must come after the CONFIG definitions, even though Set Configuration Bits doesn't do this.
Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this software question because this question belongs to stackpverflow.

Comment: This is an embedded software question thus here is probably more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

In my projects the assembly files are ".s" and directly called from the c part.

You can probably modify the makefile to use the main.S, but it is autogenerated and god knows where MPLAB hides this option.

In your case perhaps the simplest is to make a main.c and call your assembly function entry point from it like so:

```
main() {
 assemblyMain();
}
```

on the .s file:

```
.global _assemblyMain ;C called

_assemblyMain:  
    mov W0,NVMCON
    mov #0x55,W0    
    mov W0,NVMKEY
    mov #0xAA,W0
    mov W0,NVMKEY
```

Comment: Excellent suggestion.  And MPLAB X thinks you're using C which is what Microchip is pushing.

Answer (score 0):

How to create:
Projects - Source Files(right click) - New - Other... - Other - Empty File(Select) - Next - newfile.S(Type manually .S) - Finish
How to check: (Whether it is properly created)
Build the project
nbproject(find in Project.X) - configurations.xml(Open) - Search(Ctrl+f) newfile(your file name)
You can see your file name and extension.
Done!